# How to use a var in multiple methods in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have a few files in my code that speak to the database

This might look something like this:

```
def addUser():
  # some code

def verifyUser():
  # some code

def addStuffToDB():
  # some code
```

In all of the above I need to use a variable - let's call it `db` - that holds a reference to the database (as opposed to redefining it in every function)

How would I do this? How can I have functions in one or more files that all make use of a variable (in this case `db`)

Thanks

Comment: Pass the db connection into the function...

Comment: Are you familiar with arguments?

Comment: Either pass the db connection into the function as an argument as Rashid says, or wrap all these functions inside a class and define an instance variable for the db connection. Then all the functions would have access to `self.db_conn` or whatever.

Comment: This is generally what classes are for: encapsulating data that is shared between multiple functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ddejohn said, you should wrap your functions in a class, so the variable self.db would have a class scope.

```
class DB():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.db = "DB_connection or something..."


     def addUser(self):
        #Some code, acess db variable with self.db

    def verifyUser(self):
        #Some code, acess db variable with self.db

    def addStuffToDB(self):
        #Some code, acess db variable with self.db

MyDB = DB()

MyDB.addUser()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have all this functions inside the same file, it is enough to just define variable `db` outside any function (this will make it global). Now all functions will be able to see `db` variable. But if you change `db` inside a function it will not change outside the function.

If you have this variable in another file you can simple import it like

```
from file_name import db
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question.
You need to pass db as argument while calling the funcs like the following

```
db = "some referenec"
def addUser(database):
    ## now you can use db
  # some code

def verifyUser(database):
  # some code
  ## now you can use db

def addStuffToDB(database):
  # some code
## now you can use db
## while calling each func pass db as argument like this
addUser(db)
verifyUser(db)
addStuffToDB(db)
```

Answer (score 0):

add a db paramenter to yout funcs:

controller.py:

```
def addUser(db):   # some code
    obj.add(db)

def verifyUser(db):   # some code
    obj.verify(db)

def addStuffToDB(db):   # some code
    obj.add_stuff(db)
```

Then, you can use as follows:

view.py

```
import db
from controller import addUser

    
addUser(db)
```